# repeated numpy subarrays

Tags: python, numpy

This is a simplification of my question. I have a numpy array:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
```

and I have a function:

```
def f(y): return y**2
```

I can compute f(x).

Now suppose I really want to compute f(x) for a repeated x:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3])
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a repeated version of x and in a way that is transparent to f?

In my particular case, f is an involved function and one of the arguments is x. I would like to be able to calculate f when x is repeated without actually repeating it as it wont fit into memory.

Rewriting f to handle repeated x would be work and I was hoping for a clever way possibly to subclass a numpy array to do this.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for an efficient data structure to hold a matrix of the block form `(A A A)` for some matrix `A`?

Comment: @katrielex yes, that's right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can (almost) do this by using a few tricks with strides.

However, there are some major caveats...

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(4)
numrepeats = 3

y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (numrepeats,)+x.shape, (0,)+x.strides)

print y
x[0] = 9
print y
```

So, `y` is now a view into `x` where each row is `x`.  No new memory is used, and we can make `y` as large as we like.

For example, I can do this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(4)
numrepeats = 1e15

y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (numrepeats,)+x.shape, (0,)+x.strides)
```

...and not use any more memory than the 32 bytes required for `x`. (`y` would use ~8 *Petabytes* of ram, otherwise)

However, if we reshape `y` so that it only has one dimension, we'll get a copy which will use the full amount of memory.  There's no way to describe a "horizontally" tiled view of `x` using strides and shape, so any shape with less than 2 dimensions will return a copy.

Additionally, if we operate on `y` in a way that would return a copy (e.g. the `y**2` in your example), we'll get a *full* copy.

For that reason, it makes more sense to operate on things in-place. (e.g. `y **= 2`, or equivalently `x **= 2`. Both will accomplish the same thing.)

Even for a generic function, you can pass in `x` and place the result back in `x`.

E.g.

```
def f(x):
    return x**3

x[...] = f(x)
print y
```

`y` will be updated, as well, as it's just a view into `x`.